# Открыть группе пользователей доступ к одному плагину в Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

никак не могу открыть для группы пользователей доступ только к одному плагину, остальные функции админки должны быть отключены.
Подробнее: Есть плагин, который используется как таблица прайс-листа **Data Tables Generator by Supsystic**
Необходимо открыть доступ только к нему для определенной группы (условно Менеджер прайса).
Пробовал через **User Role Editor** - безрезультатно , не получается выдать доуступ только к одному плагину. В настройках **URE** вкладки с нужным плагином нет :/ есть только основные Ядро, страницы и пр.
Быть может есть какой то хук, чтобы в functions прописать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению Plugin Organizer не подошел. Но я решил эту проблему более кардинально.
В functions.php прописал хук, который скрывает необходимые пункты меню для определенного пользователя с уникальным email

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_admin_menu_links', 999);
function remove_admin_menu_links() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( $user && isset($user->user_email) ) {
     if (('yourmail1@gmail.com' == $user->user_email) || ('MAIL@GMAIL.COM' == $user->user_email)) {
remove_menu_page('index.php');                # Консоль 
    remove_menu_page('edit.php');                 # Записи 
    remove_menu_page('edit-comments.php');        # Комментарии 
    remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=page');  # Страницы 
    remove_menu_page('upload.php');               # Медиафайлы 
    remove_menu_page('themes.php');               # Внешний вид 
    remove_menu_page('plugins.php');              # Плагины 
    remove_menu_page('users.php');                # Пользователи 
    remove_menu_page('tools.php');                # Инструменты 
    remove_menu_page('options-general.php');      # Параметры 
    remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=acf-field-group'); # ACF
    remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=content_block'); #БЛОКИ
    remove_menu_page('wpcf7');    #CF
    remove_menu_page('theme-general-settings');    #THEME SETTINGS
    remove_menu_page('wp-mail-smtp');    #SMTP
    remove_menu_page('duplicator');    #DUPLICATOR
    remove_menu_page('sucuriscan');    #SCAN
    remove_menu_page('Wordfence');    #WF
    remove_menu_page('options-framework');        
 
    }
 }
}
```

Чтобы узнать slug плагина и исключить его из выдачи в админ панели в functions прописал следущее

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_136058_debug_admin_menu' );
function wpse_136058_debug_admin_menu() {
    echo '<pre>' . print_r( $GLOBALS[ 'menu' ], TRUE) . '</pre>';
}
```

В админке отобразится массив данных, где элементы показывают опции по каждому из пунктов меню

Comment: Почему Organizer "не подошёл"?

Comment: Скрывать - плохой метод. Но ещё хуже - писать такой функционал в файл функций. Это должно быть в плагине. И есть готовые плагины для этого.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте плагин Plugin Organizer. В нём есть функция [Disable by Role](https://wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-organizer/#can%20i%20disable%20plugins%20by%20role%3F).